# Add Rewrite Rule for custom page

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Was trying to create author specific page with author specific URL and it was working fine,but when i created this URL did not taken in to account following 2 factors

1. Author Name Conflict (similar name).
2. Paging option to be added to author page (for his published posts)

here is my initial rule

```
function add_my_rule() {    
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('args');   
    add_rewrite_rule('writer\/(.*)','index.php?pagename=writer&args=$matches[1]','top'); 
    /*global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();*/
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');
```

This was working file for a URL say

```
www.myblog.com/writer/umesh-awasthi ,
```

but there can be more author with same name and this will create a issue.So i was planning to have Blog author URL like SO have

`www.myblog.com/writer/001/umesh-awasthi` where `001` is user id which will always be unique.

second issue is with paging, as i am able to create paging on the author page but when user is clicking second page the URL is coming as

`http://localhost/blog/wordpress/writer/umesh-awasthi/page/2/` so as per my URL-Rewrite rule i will get following data as parameter `umesh-awasthi/page/2` which means that now my query will not work as it will expect the author name as `umesh-awasthi` and will get it as `umesh-awasthi/page/2`

My Question is can i rewrite the rule so that i should get data in following way in three different variables

1. userid
2. author name
3. page number (if it exits)
   being new to the WP and rewrite i am not sure how i can achieve this
   thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function add_my_rule() {    
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('args');   
    $wp->add_query_var('arg_username');
    add_rewrite_rule('writer/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)','index.php?pagename=writer&args=$matches[1]&arg_username=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('writer/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)','index.php?pagename=writer&args=$matches[1]&arg_username=$matches[2]','top');
    /*global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();*/
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');
```

This should do the trick. One rewriterule for writer/user_id/username (username isn't used in the rewriterule but is necessarily to make it work. The second rewriterule is the same except that it adds pagination.

---

EDIT: added arg_username in code above.

Comment: this is not working as expected, using the above rule giving me only the `user-id` not writer name, that means for `www.myblog.com/writer/001/umesh-awasthi` the rule above giving me only `001` and not the writer-name

Comment: It is working as I said in my answer. If you have the user ID you don't need the username. If you want both then you can add another queryvar (like arg_username) and add it to the rewriterule: `add_rewrite_rule('writer/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)','index.php?pagename=writer&args=$matches[1]&arg_username=$matches[2]','top');` (also change it in the other reriterule)

Comment: may be doing some wrong due to lack of knowledge but `add_rewrite_rule('writer/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)','index.php?pagename=writer&args=$matches[1]','top'); 
    add_rewrite_rule('writer/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)','index.php?pagename=writer&args=$matches[1]&arg_username=$matches[2]','top');
 add_rewrite_rule('writer/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)','index.php?pagename=writer&args=$matches[1]&arg_username=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]','top'); ` rule still not giving me author name.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately value of `$paged` always coming `0`, i even changed the value to `$page_num` and added this to my function `$wp->add_query_var('paged_num');`but nothing got worked

Comment: My bad, check updated answer (rewriterule for paged had to be on top).