# Adding paged query to custom URL rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have set up the following to create 'pretty' post type and category permalinks:

```
function kdev_add_category_rules() {

    $post_types = array(
        'kdev_photos',
        'kdev_videos',
        'kdev_articles'  
    );

    foreach($post_types as $post_type) {
        $pt_obj = get_post_type_object($post_type);
        $pt_rewrite = $pt_obj->rewrite;
        $pt_slug = $pt_rewrite['slug'];

        add_rewrite_rule('^'.$pt_slug.'/category/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&category_name=$matches[1]','top');

    }

}

add_action( "init", "kdev_add_category_rules" );
```

This works great. When I visit sitename.com/photos/category/landscape/ I get all the 'photos' in the 'landscape' category.

Unfortunately, my pagination on these pages is broken.

I would like sitename.com/photos/category/landscape/page/2 to show the second page in this query. Currently it just refreshes the same page. On inspection of the query paged=1.

I've tried the following, but my knowledge of regex is poor.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^'.$pt_slug.'/category/([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)/?','index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
```

What is the correct rewrite rule?

## Progress

Interestingly, removing the first 'add_rewrite_rule' allows the new one to work (but obviuosly breaks all the other rewrites). I.e. /photos/category/test-category/page/2/ will work, but /photos/category/test-category/ won't.

## EDIT: Additional info

I have refreshed the permalinks loads!

On sitename.com/photos/category/landscape/page/2/, `get_query_var('paged')` is returning `1`.

/category/test-category/page/2/ and /photos/page/2/ both work.

Post types being created using:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Photos', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Photo', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Photos', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Photo:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Photos', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Photos', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Photo', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'New Photo', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Photo', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Photo', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search photos', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'No photos found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No photos found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
);

$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'kdev_photos', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Shared photos', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title' ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'photos' ),
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);

register_post_type( 'kdev_photos', $args );
}
```

The site is using the Roots theme which uses Scribu's theme wrapper technique.

The first template called is base.php:

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) {
wp_redirect( get_bloginfo('url').'/photos/', 302 );
exit;
} ?>
<?php get_template_part('templates/head'); ?>
<?php
$post_type_query = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
if(!is_array($post_type_query)) $post_type = $post_type_query;
?>
<body <?php body_class($post_type); ?>>

  <?php
    do_action('get_header');
    // Use Bootstrap's navbar if enabled in config.php
    if (current_theme_supports('bootstrap-top-navbar')) {
      get_template_part('templates/header-top-navbar');
    } else {
      get_template_part('templates/header');
    }
  ?>

  <div class="wrap container" role="document">
    <div class="content row">
      <div class="main <?php echo roots_main_class(); ?>" role="main">
        <?php include roots_template_path(); ?>
      </div><!-- /.main -->
      <?php if (roots_display_sidebar()) : ?>
      <aside class="sidebar <?php echo roots_sidebar_class(); ?>" role="complementary">
          <div class="well">
            <?php include roots_sidebar_path(); ?>
          </div>
      </aside><!-- /.sidebar -->
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- /.content -->
  </div><!-- /.wrap -->

  <?php get_template_part('templates/footer'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Which then calls index.php:

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/page', 'header'); ?>

<?php  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  ?>

<h1>Currently Browsing Page <?php echo $paged; ?></h1>

<?php if (!have_posts()) : ?>
  <div class="alert">
    <?php _e('Sorry, no results were found.', 'roots'); ?>
  </div>
  <?php get_search_form(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php 
$post_type_query = get_query_var( 'post_type' );
if($post_type_query == 'kdev_photos') $use_grid = TRUE; else $use_grid = FALSE; ?>

<?php
if($use_grid) echo '<ul class="thumbnails">'; 
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  if($use_grid) get_template_part('templates/content', 'photo');
  else get_template_part('templates/content', get_post_format());  
endwhile;  
if($use_grid) echo '</ul>'; ?>

<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

$pag_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'end_size' => 1,
    'mid_size' => 1,
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
) );

echo '<div class="pagination">'.$pag_links.'</div>';

?>
```

Comment: What if you change `&page=` to `&paged=`? see [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39450/add-rewrite-rule-for-custom-page) question for more information.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks, but that doesn't seem to change things. I've updated the question to include your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you need to add the following rewrite rule in your foreach loop:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^'.$pt_slug.'/category/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?','index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
```

Comment: Thanks Brady but still doesn't work! Can you suggest and tests that I could run?

Comment: Install monkeyman rewrite analyzer plugin, reload your permalink then go to wp-admin->tools->rewrite-analyzer and start typing in your url that you think should be paged by the above rewrite. It should show you rules that match.

Comment: The rule that it shows is exactly the one that you suggested. Still no joy though. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Can you add to your original question how you are adding your CPT's and any template file you are trying to use to show your content

Comment: Also make sure you add the second rule in the right order to your first one so that the new rule has precedence over the original.