# Creating template page for my plugin in WordPress

Tags: plugins

I was following a tutorial, but when they have done it, there was an option for the plugin and the form page was showing, but in my case it did not work. Do I need to add action hook?

The code is as follows:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Login Form Plugin
Author: Mitaly
version: 0.0.3
Description: This is a custom plugin
*/
<?php
//add custom page fanction
function DBP_add_front_page(){
  //include insertion code
  include_once("form_template.php");
  DBP_insert_data();
}
//define absolute path to avoid direct ArrayAccess
 if(!defined('ABSPATH'))
 {
   define('ABSPATH',dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

 }

 //including database files

 include_once("employess-form.php");

 //register hook

 register_activation_hook(__FILE__,"DBP_tb_create");

 //filter
 add_filter('page_template','DBP_add_front_page');
  ?>
```

Comment: Do you have that plugin header echoed above the `<?php` tag in your actual plugin file?

Comment: I was trying to add a submenu on plugin ,after using an admin hook ,it worked

Comment: yeah,i corrected it ,the comment will go after the php tag

Comment: So, all good now? If not, then what exactly isn't working? The plugin options form isn't showing? But you're not correctly using the [`page_template` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_template).

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: Have a look at this post. I wrote an answer a couple of days ago. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/368055/use-an-empty-page-to-build-custom-plugin-output/368142#368142

Comment: @MitalyTabassum Then I'm presuming all is good now, but if not, edit your question and tell us what you've done so far and what is still not working.